# Google tag manager - How can I push the Fields to set into Google Analytics?

Tags: search, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Im trying to:

**See what Search Queries in my Site search gives the visitor 0 search results.**

This is what I get from the Site search tag:

```js
Event Action 'Submit search'
Event Category 'Search'
Event Label 0
Fields to Set {page: '/sok?q=helloworld', anonymizeIp: 'true'}
```

What I want in Google Analytics is to see what Search query (in this case "helloworld") gave me Event label 0.

Answer (score 1):

One issue you'll have to figure out is, "How are you doing to determine that there were 0 search results returned?" since you only want to fire the event when there are no results. Are you going to scrape the page, or will you set up a listener, or will you do a dataLayer push (I recommend the last method)?

If you do a dataLayer push, then you'll have to also push an `event`

```
dataLayer.push({
   'event': 'search results',
   'numResults': 0
})
```

Once you have that in place, then you would need to create a `URL` type variable with the `Query` component type set with the `Query key` of `q`. Also create other associated variables, like `numResults`.

Then in your event tag, you can set the `page` field with that GTM variable, do your other settings, and then fire the tag on the `search results` event and when `numResults = 0`, all pushed from the dataLayer.